# tmux status line not updating itself after logging on to another server

Tags: shell, terminal, tmux

I have created a tmux configuration file myself by reading the manual page and looking through examples and reading articles. I know there are some tools available to make this a lot easier but i'd rather learn the tmux config syntax myself so im not dependent on other third party tools.

Ive configured a fairly simple tmux configuration and these two lines:

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=yellow]#(uptime | cut -d "," -f 2-) - CPUs: #(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i processor | wc -l) - IOwait: #(vmstat | grep [0-9] | awk {"print \\$16"}) % - Memory: #(free -m | grep [0-9] | awk {"print \\$2"}) MB (total) - #(free -m | grep -i buffers | grep [0-9] | awk {"print \\$4"}) MB (available) - #(free -m | grep -i buffer | grep [0-9] | awk {"print \\$3"}) MB (used) @ #(uname -n)'

set -g status-left '#[fg=yellow]#(date)'
```

are working as expected as long as i dont log on to another server. If i log on to another server the values keep updating itself but values from the first server i logged on are still being used and i dont really understand why since i have a status interval of 5 seconds and its only some shell commands that are suppose to be run on the new host i connected to.

Does someone know why tmux is still running the same commands on the first host ive logged on to and still do so even if i log on to another server ? (i would expect that the commands would be run on the new server i logged in to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you have logged on to another server, `tmux` itself is still running on the host machine, so that is where `uptime` et al. are still running.

Comment: is there any way to make it run on the new servers i connect to so i always will have the updated information on the new servers i log on..i dont really see the usefullness of a status bar like this if that isnt possible.. the first server i usually log on to is a login server and that isnt very usefull to get that information from

Comment: Either run `tmux` on the remote server, or embed an `ssh` command (using a locally updated environment variable to hold the correct host name) in your status bar. The status bar is meant to show information on your local host; the remote login is just another program running in your shell as far as `tmux` is concerned.

Comment: then i will have to copy the tmux configuration to all hosts so it would be easier to update bashrc on all servers..one of the benefits or tmux is to have multiple terminals in one tmux session and not one tmux process for each connection but thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, but `tmux` does not have any knowledge of what happens on the remote sessions; it simply helps you manage the local processes that provide the remote connections.